# R: Generate a dummy variable based on the existence of one column' value in another column

Tags: r, if-statement, dummy-variable, any

I have a data frame like this:

```
A                    B          
2012,2013,2014     2011
2012,2013,2014     2012
2012,2013,2014     2013
2012,2013,2014     2014
2012,2013,2014     2015
```

I wanted to create a dummy variable, which indicates whether the value in column B exists in column A. 1 indicates the existence, and 0 indicates non-existant. Such that,

```
A                    B       dummy        
2012,2013,2014     2011        0
2012,2013,2014     2012        1
2012,2013,2014     2013        1
2012,2013,2014     2014        1
2012,2013,2014     2015        0
```

I have tried to use `%in%` to achieve this:

```
df$dummy <- ifelse(df$B %in% df$A, 1, 0)
```

but it turned out that everything in the column of `dummy` is `1`.

Same situation happened when I tried to use another method `any()`:

```
df$dummy <- any(df$A==df$B)
```

everything in the column of `dummy` is `TRUE`.

Is there an efficient way to generate this dummy variable?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like column `A` is a string of numbers separated by commas, so `%in%` would not be appropriate (it would be helpful if, for example, you checked for `B` inside a vector of multiple strings, or numbers if `A` and `B` were numeric). If your data frame structure is different, please let me know (and feel free to edit your question).

You probably could accomplish this multiple ways. Perhaps an easy way is to use `grepl` one row at a time to identify if column `B` is present in `A`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(dummy = +grepl(B, A))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  A              B     dummy
  <fct>          <fct> <int>
1 2012,2013,2014 2011      0
2 2012,2013,2014 2012      1
3 2012,2013,2014 2013      1
4 2012,2013,2014 2014      1
5 2012,2013,2014 2015      0
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(rep("2012,2013,2014", 5)),
  B = c("2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use base R:

```
df <- data.frame(A = rep("2012,2013,2014", 5), B = c("2011", "2012","2013","2014","2015"))

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
     df$dummy[i] <- grepl(df$B[i],df$A[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Making a tab-separated file:

```
A   B          
2012,2013,2014  2011
2012,2013,2014  2012
2012,2013,2014  2013
2012,2013,2014  2014
2012,2013,2014  2015
```

Here's a way using `str_detect` from [stringr](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_detect.html):

```
read.table('test.txt', header = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(
    B = as.character(B),
    dummy = case_when(
      str_detect(pattern = B, fixed(A)) ~ '1',
      TRUE ~ '0'
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using `tidyverse`. The main problem is that `A` is being read as a string. My solution first separates each number into different columns, and afterwards compares `B` to these numbers.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  #Separate A into separate numbers
  separate(col = A,
           sep = ",",
           into = c("S1","S2","S3")) %>%
  #Compare B to the new columns and fill dummy
  mutate(dummy = ifelse(B %in% c(S1,S2,S3), 1, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for this comment, Jonathan. The col A above is just an example - this column in the actual data frame may have more/fewer than 3 numbers. So I guess a more automatic way would better fit this problem. I already have the answer, but thanks anyway!